# How to trigger an animation when an item in listbox is selected

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events

I got a listbox composed of two choices:

```
<table width="auto" height="auto" style="position:relative; top:100px;">
  <tr>
    <td><select name="payment_selection"></td>
    <td>
       <option id="sel_cash" value="">Cash - pay in station</option>
       <option id="sel_account" value="">Customer account</option>
    </td>
    </select>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When the customer select <kbd>Cash - pay in station</kbd>,
this should appear below:

```
<td>Total</td>
<td><?php //code ?></td>
```

When the customer selects <kbd>Customer account</kbd>,
this should appear below by JavaScript:

```
<td>Your remaining balance is</td>
<td><?php //code ?></td>
```

Can you suggest me some code? I only knew about buttons by `onclick` function
but not a listbox and with a selection. Hope the title is correct in my problem.

Comment: why do you have the drop down mixed in your table.. put it all in one cell

Answer (score 0):

```
<table width="auto" height="auto" style="position:relative; top:100px;">
      <tr>
        <td><select onchange="somefunction();" name="payment_selection"></td>
        <td>
           <option id="sel_cash" value="">Cash - pay in station</option>
           <option id="sel_account" value="">Customer account</option>
        </td>
        </select>
      </tr>
    </table>
<script>
function somefunction(){
alert("value changed!");
}
</scrip>
```

i think you know what will happen with this

Answer (score -1):

`$( '#payment_selection' ).bind({

    'change': function( event ) {

        alert( $( this ).val() );

    }

});`